# The UE4 Pixel Streaming webpage never gets past "starting connection to server please wait", but only when connecting from home

Tags: webrtc, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a project for a startup company. We are trying to run a 3D product demo on our website using Pixel Streaming. I'm hosting the application and the signaling server from a dedicated machine inside the office. I have gotten Pixel Streaming to work on computers inside the office, one remote computer, and on 4G. However, when I'm trying to work from home, the player screen hangs while waiting for a connection. On checking the output log, the only difference between when it works and when it doesn't, is that when it does not work I see this:

```
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #0 (0) dropped
PixelStreamingWebRTC: (video_stream_encoder.cc:790): Dropping frame. Too large for target bitrate.
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #1 (0) dropped
PixelStreamingWebRTC: (video_stream_encoder.cc:790): Dropping frame. Too large for target bitrate.
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #2 (0) dropped
PixelStreamingWebRTC: (video_stream_encoder.cc:790): Dropping frame. Too large for target bitrate.
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #3 (0) dropped
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #4 (0) dropped
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #5 (0) dropped
LogAVEncoder: Buffer #6 (0) dropped
```

and it goes on like that until I close the webpage.

What does this mean?